# Colocar ícone dentro jLabel num jTextField

Tags: java, swing

Como alterar o modo de inserção da data no meu `jTextField`?

O que eu tenho é o seguinte:

[image: SS]

Quero inserir esse ícone que está num `jLabel` dentro do meu `jTextField`. Será isto possível?

**Atualizar:**

```
    import java.awt.*;  
import javax.swing.*;  
class Testing extends JFrame  
{  
  public Testing()  
  {  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());  
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(5);  
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("LogoIcon.png"));  
    label.setOpaque(true);  
    label.setBackground(tf.getBackground());  
    label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(label.getPreferredSize().width,tf.getPreferredSize().height));  
    p.setBorder(tf.getBorder());  
    tf.setBorder(null);  
    p.add(label,BorderLayout.WEST);  
    p.add(tf,BorderLayout.CENTER);  
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();  
    p1.add(p);  
    getContentPane().add(p1);  
    pack();  
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
  }  
  public static void main(String[] args){new Testing().setVisible(true);}  
}
```

Esse código está funcional e consigo por o icone que quero no textfield. Agora eu já tenho o meu jformattedTextField e a minha label com o icon e tentei o seguinte:

```
jLabel31.setOpaque(true);  
jLabel31.setBackground(teste.getBackground());  
jLabel31.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(jLabel31.getPreferredSize().width,teste.getPreferredSize().height));
```

dessa forma a imagem não me aparece no meu textField 'teste'. Alguma sugestão?

**Atualizar1:**

```
public ConfEmpresa() throws SQLException {
...
        Testing1 teste = new Testing1();
        teste.setVisible(true);


    }

class Testing1 extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    public Testing1() {


        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        //Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1);
        //jp.setBorder(border);
        //jp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jp.addMouseListener(this);

        //nomeC = new JTextField(10);
        nomeC.setEditable(false);
        nomeC.setText("sdfasdf");
        //nomeC.setBorder(null);
        //tf.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        nomeC.addMouseListener(this);

        JLabel lb = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("LogoIcon.png"));
        lb.addMouseListener(this);

        //jp.add(nomeC);
        jp.add(lb);
        jPanel3.add(jp);
        pack();
    }
```

A parte do mouseclicked já está como eu quero. Continuam é a abrir duas janelas e o icon não aparece no campo.

Comment: Esse ícone possui alguma funcionalidade implementada ou é somente uma indicação que este é o campo data?

Comment: Esse icon faz abrir o jcalendar para escolher a data.

Comment: De uma lida nesse [topico](http://www.coderanch.com/t/343579/GUI/java/Inserting-Image-JTextField)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA6don86wq0 Olha este video a ver se te ajuda, mais precisamente a partir do minuto 3...

Comment: Obrigado aos dois pelas dicas. DaniloOliveira vi o código que puseste e está funcional, agora queria adaptá-lo ao meu. vou editar a minha pergunta e ver se alguém me ajuda a adaptar ao que tenho. jsantos1991 Obrigado pelo vídeo, sem dúvida que poderá ajudar-me e muito porque o objetivo é ao clicar no dia, selecionar logo a data, e no jCalendar isso parece-me ser mais complexo para fazer. vamos lá ver. Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Sua imagem não aparece pois você definiu `label.setOpaque(true);` e isso está cobrindo ela!

**Sugestão:**

Já implementei o evento de clique pra você, agora basta manipulá-lo para editar o `JTextField` de acordo com a forma que vai utilizar para capturar a data do usuário.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

class Testing extends JFrame implements MouseListener {

    JTextField tf;

    public Testing() {
        super("Exemplo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(200, 75);

        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 1);
        jp.setBorder(border);
        jp.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jp.addMouseListener(this);

        tf = new JTextField(10);
        tf.setEditable(false);
        tf.setText("___/___/______");
        tf.setBorder(null);
        tf.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        tf.addMouseListener(this);

        JLabel lb = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/home/anderson/Downloads/icon-calendar.png"));
        lb.addMouseListener(this);

        jp.add(tf);
        jp.add(lb);
        add(jp);
        pack();
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Manipule a data aqui!");
        tf.setText("13/11/2014");
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Após o evento do mouse:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado! Qualquer dúvida, estou a disposição.

Comment: Desde já obrigado por ajudar. A questão principal e à qual ainda não me sinto à vontade é a seguinte: Nesse exemplo, tu crias o textField e tudo isso. Mas eu já tenho o meu design definido e com os campos lá. Não consigo pegar simplesmente nos nomes dos labels e TextFields que tenho e adaptá-los ao código?

Comment: Consegue sim. Utilize o exemplo acima como modelo que vai funcionar! Lembre de implementar o MouseListener e criar os seus respectivos métodos...

Comment: E é necessário estar a criar no meu código, um panel, como você criou aí nesse exemplo, que já testei e funcionou perfeitamente, vito que eu já tenho o design feito?

Comment: Sim. Crie o painel e coloque os seus componentes dentro dele, da mesma forma que eu fiz. Depois adicione o painel ao seu layout

Comment: Se calhar o meu problema está mesmo aí, é que não estou a adicionar o painel ao meu layout. É que eu ao correr o código, abre-me o meu layout, mais esse seu ! Eu só quero adaptar ao meu código :s Sou mesmo leigo nisto -.-

Olhando à minha pergunta inicial, é visível um textField que se chama 'nomeC' e o label que tem o ícone é o 'jLabel33'. Como posso adaptar esse seu exemplo a estes campos que eu já tenho?

Comment: Seu problema deve estar no método add(); Utilize seuJPanel_ou_Layout.add(meuJPanel);

Comment: Já consegui por o campo que quero clicável como no seu código, mas não me está a por a imagem no campo -.- e continuam a abrir duas janelas, vou editar a pergunta para você ver como está.

Comment: Rodei seu trecho de código e funcionou! Esse jPanel3 é onde todos os outros componentes do seu programa são adicionados?

Comment: Sim é onde estão todos os componentes. E apareceu-te a imagem no campo ?

Comment: Sim, só descomentei as linhas, mudei o path da imagem e alterei tf.setBackground(...) pra nomeC.setBackground(...);

Comment: Eu testei agora descomentar as linhas do meu trecho de código e não funcionou. De qualquer forma agradeço a disponibilidade para ajudar :)